# How should we go about promoting this site?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Once we enter into public beta, we'll have to try to ensure that the site meets the minimum criteria for acceptance here:

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/45110?phase=beta

Not just so that we pass the SE quotas, but so that the site actually becomes a lasting resource. Obviously, this means we'll have to promote the site to the best of our abilities.

I'm sure we all have leads for spreading the word about this site personally, but we should probably discuss ways of coordinating our efforts over the long-term if we are to cultivate a lasting community here.

What are some methods we all should be thinking about in terms of increasing awareness about this resource?

Here is a link with a few ideas to get us started:

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/a-recipe-to-promote-your-site/

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a good idea to learn from the other religion related Q&As we have. Are there *interesting* questions you could ask to attract the attention of Google visitors? What kind of advertisement/promotion did those other sites put up?

We are going to have Hinduism into public beta soon as well, I think the two can coexist and help each other greatly.

---

Basically, the key to a successful site is the quality of its content. Ask, answer, vote, discuss (in chat). Keep the site alive and vibrant. Edit questions to eliminate typos, grammar errors and raise the quality bar higher. Once you do, you'll get visitors naturally coming from Google and users will be happy to stay.

Comment: Hinduism is a cesspool at the moment. I would not suggest counting on any good coming of collaborating with them for the time being.

Comment: I'm sure you mean the quality of the questions & the rigor that people are following the SE way of doing things.

Answer (score 1):

I have posted a link to Google+ Buddhism and Meditation community with ~38k followers.
That said, I don't think we should rush with promoting the site, until we figure out our format as to appropriate questions and answers. Otherwise we can get an influx of fun but disorganized content.

Answer (score 0):

One important idea in the above link is to break up this question into smaller questions, so maybe people will come up with ideas and open questions on how to make those ideas a reality. I'll try to post some ideas as questions myself.

Answer (score 0):

We still have quite a way to go in promoting the site.  According to http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/45110/buddhism we have about 300 visits a day while SE says that even 500 visits per day "needs some work."